# Prevent typeahead.js dropdown from closing on select

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, jquery-events, typeahead.js, typeahead

How can I prevent a typeahead dropdown from closing when an item is selected? I've tried using `preventDefault` like this:

```
$('#q').bind('typeahead:selected',function(obj, datum, name) {  
            ...
            obj.preventDefault();
        });
```

But no success.

Edit:
I've managed to "fix" this by building Typeahead with lines 217-218 commented from typeahead_views.js:

```
  byClick && utils.isMsie() ?
       utils.defer(this.dropdownView.close) : this.dropdownView.close();
```

But there has to be another way without modifying source files?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem and the (very easy) solution doesn't seem to be documented anywhere

```
$(document).on('typeahead:beforeclose', function(event, data) {
  event.preventDefault()
})
```

(this just prevents the dropdown from closing at all which can be very helpful during development, use `'typeahead:beforeselect'` if you want to prevent closing just on selet).

Answer (score 0):

Trigger the focus of the input on the closed callback.

```
    $('#typeahead-input').on('typeahead:closed', function(e, d) {
      $('#typeahead-input').focus();
    });
```

Comment: I find that this still closes the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on typeahead inside tokenfield so the first part is me accessing the Typeahead.dropdown object, which in itself took some hunting.

Tried toying with `isOpen` or overwriting `close` functions, in the end closest I got was this. Breaking down the marshalling of events. You'd have to reimplement any saving of values etc, basically the first 3 lines of `Typeahead.select`.

I myself was blocked at being able to put a form (focus stays in input field) in the dropdown and still a bit more hunting if were to put something interactive in there. Think I'll go for a roll-your-own solution on this one but might help someone who just wants to block the closing, put the original function in a var to put it back in place when you're finished.

```
$('input[id="test"]').data('bs.tokenfield')
    .$input.data('ttTypeahead').dropdown.trigger = function(e) {};
```

Also this has potential:

```
$('input[id="test"]').data('bs.tokenfield')
    .$input.data('ttTypeahead').eventBus.trigger = function(e) {};
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way:

```
     input.data('tt-typeahead')._selectOld = input.data('tt-typeahead')._select
     input.data('tt-typeahead')._select = function(datum) {
       if (false)
         this._selectOld(datum)
     }
```