# Prevent latest Twitter typeahed from closing when clicking on a suggestion?

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead.js

Before flagging this question as duplicate please note I've checked out all of these links and none work with the latest version v0.11.1:

- https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/731
- [Prevent typeahead.js dropdown from closing on select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20182058/prevent-typeahead-js-dropdown-from-closing-on-select)
- [How to prevent Twitter typeahead from filling in the input with the selected value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24417527/how-to-prevent-twitter-typeahead-from-filling-in-the-input-with-the-selected-val)
- [Prevent typeahead dataset from closing on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25257996/prevent-typeahead-dataset-from-closing-on-click)

My typeahed contains a form with an input. I need to not to close the dropdown when user click a suggestion.

Is there a reliable way to prevent close? The obvious way it's not working (https://jsfiddle.net/gcgdqfxp/):

```
$('.typeahed').on('typeahead:select', function (event, obj) {
    // not working
    event.preventDefault();

    // not working
    return false;
});
```

> typeahead:select – Fired when a suggestion is selected. The event handler will be invoked with 2 arguments: the jQuery event object and the suggestion object that was selected.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah!!! Found a solution looking at the source [here](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/dist/typeahead.jquery.js#L1252) the (undocumented) "typeahead:beforeselect" event is triggered before actually trigger the "typeahead:select", so it's easy to stop propagation (https://jsfiddle.net/gcgdqfxp/2/) like:

```
$('.typeahead').bind('typeahead:beforeselect', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```